# Take limited files from directory and insert them into another directory

Tags: bash, macos, directory

I have directory that contains **80.000 images** , i want to insert randomly **30.000 images** from this directory  into another directory using *Bash*  commands .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're in the directory where the 80000 images are and your other directory is called target, this should work:

```
ls | shuf | head -n 30000 | xargs -i cp "{}" target/.
```

Comment: I had first to install shuf on mac using brew install coreutils  , now it works .Thanks

Comment: pleased to hear! :)

Comment: While the answer is correct `xargs -i` is deprecated and you should use `xargs -I` instead

Answer (score 0):

While the provided answer is correct `shuf` is not installed on all systems so you might consider to use `sort -R` instead. I quote the man page:

> Sort by a random order.  This is a random permutation of the inputs
>   except that the equal keys sort together.  It is implemented by
>   hashing the input keys and sorting the hash values. The hash function
>   is chosen randomly.  The hash function is randomized by /dev/random
>   content, or by file content if it is specified by --random-source. 
>   Even if multiple sort fields are specified, the same random hash
>   function is used for all of them.

As long as you do not have any duplicates (exactly the same file just with a different name) and you do not want to install `shuf` or any other tool you can use this to get a 'random' sort.

```
ls | sort -R | tail -n 30000 | xargs -I "{}" cp "{}" ./target
```

Comment: While the `-I` is the new canonical way of doing this your incantation is incomplete, and should result in `xargs: {}: No such file or directory` unless you specify `-I"{}"` ... also note that `shuf` is magnitudes faster than `sort -R`.